# AWK with RS not matching a patten

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract a "paragraph" from an file.  There are not blank lines between paragraphs, but there are lines that do not have text between > <.  My approach is to designate RS record separators to be lines that do not have the pattern >*<

file.txt is:

```
  <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
  <text:p text:style-name="P11"/>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">1</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">2</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">3 this is line that matches</text:p>>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">4</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">5</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
```

My attempt at the code is

```
$ awk '/matches/' RS=^">"*"<" file.txt
```

Desired output is:

```
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">1</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">2</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">3 this is line that matches</text:p>>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">4</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="P10">5</text:p>
```

But instead the whole file is output.
What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

if file.xml is

```
<long line of alphanumerics, slashes, single and double quotes><more or the same><and many more>
      <office:text>
      <text:sequence-decls>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Table"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Text"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Drawing"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Figure"/>
      </text:sequence-decls>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the first line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the third line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">and this is some more text that is to be included</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the sixth. I want it included,</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">with this line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">and this one</text:p>
    </office:text>
```

and use

```
$ awk '/line/' RS='\n[ \t]*<[^>]*>\n' file.xml
```

The whole file is output, while i am looking for:

```
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the first line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the third line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">and this is some more text that is to be included</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the sixth. I want it included,</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">with this line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">and this one</text:p>
```

Comment: TBH I'm not sure what you're shooting for with `RS=^">"*"<"`. I'm not certain how `^` is interpreted in this context (remember it is `RS` that normally separates the input into "lines" in the first place) and `">"*` will mean zero or more instances of `>` (at least so long as it doesn't match any filenames - in general you should avoid such unquoted shell metacharacters). You could try something like `RS='\n[ \t]*<[^>]*>\n'` but I'd want to see a larger input sample to verify.

Comment: Notice that each line that is desired has within it the pattern, as example:  >1<  but there are lines before the >1< and after the >5< which do not. I seek to make such lines be taken as record separators,

Comment: So RS = lines which do not (^) contain pattern >wildcard<

Comment: OK so that's not going to work - `^` is only a negation inside `[ ]` character classes (otherwise it matches start-of-string) - and awk patterns are interpreted as *extended regular expressions* not wildcards (so for instance `*` is a quantifier, not a match-all wildcard on its own)

Comment: I appended more information to my original post.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I have reposted the question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280858/awk-with-rs-not-matching-a-pattern-asking-again-becuase-i-accidently-labled-as