# AWK with RS not matching a pattern (asking again becuase I accidently labled as solved. Better explanation ths time.)

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I have an odt file with blank lines between lines of text. I want to search for a term and output the whole group of text where there is a match to the term. My approach is to say that the blank lines in the odt file are the record separators.  Odt files are zip archives with the text contained in content.xml. After unzipping the odt file, I have used xmllint --format content.xml to insert newlines (as below) and "blank" lines are actually lines without text in between > and <. So I want to set RS to be any such line that does not have text between > and <.  If the formatted content.xml file is as follows:

```
<long line of alphanumerics, slashes, single and double quotes><more or the same><and many more>
      <office:text>
      <text:sequence-decls>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Table"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Text"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Drawing"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Figure"/>
      </text:sequence-decls>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the first line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the third line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">and this is some more text that is to be included</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the sixth. I want it included,</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">with this line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">and this one</text:p>
    </office:text>
```

and code is

```
$ awk '/line/' RS='\n[ \t]*<[^>]*>\n' file.xml
```

The whole file is output. But I only want:

```
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the first line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the third line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">and this is some more text that is to be included</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">This is the sixth. I want it included,</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">with this line</text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="P1">and this one</text:p>
```

Comment: What is your actual end goal here? are you sure you don't want something like `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//office:body/office:text/text:p" -n content.xml` instead?

Comment: I want to search for a word and extract the whole paragraph. Each paragraph consists of a number of lines and is separated from other paragraphs by a blank line in the ODT file. (btw, I can't grep  -A -B -C because the number of lines above or below the match is not consistent, although maybe I could get a count for each match, but it seems that the RS approach would be simpler). I don't know much about xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question by following inspiration from steeldriver, I modified the file, before using awk:

```
sed '/>.*</! s/.*/---/' test.txt > modfile.txt  # overwrites lines matching the pattern with what I will name as the record separator, “---”
```

Then I was able to extract the entire record on matches of $searchterm

```
awk "/$searchterm/" RS="---" modfile.txt > results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fraught with problems. Most importantly, there's no obvious way to restrict the regex match to the body text of the document - in the case of `/line/` for example, that's going to match tags such as `<text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/>`

(There's also an issue with your `RS` regex consuming two newlines, which will prevent it from properly handling adjacent separators; `RS='\n([ \t]*<[^>]*>\n)+'` *might* fix that but I won't guarantee it).

Instead, what I'd suggest is extracting the document's body text first and **then** applying awk in "traditional" paragraph mode (i.e. using the empty record separator):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//office:body/office:text/text:p" -n content.xml | 
  awk -v RS= '/line/{print $0 ORS}'
```

or with GNU awk, preserving the actual record separators as parsed:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//office:body/office:text/text:p" -n content.xml | 
  gawk -v RS= '/line/{printf $0 RT}'
```

You could even omit the intermediate file altogether, piping stdout from `unzip -p`:

```
unzip -p somefile.odt content.xml | 
  xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//office:body/office:text/text:p" -n - | gawk -v RS= '/line/{printf $0 RT}'
```

Comment: Sorry, I been so long on this particular this task I for forgot to say that I need to preserve the formatting information contained within the XML. The accumulation of such searches is to be zipped into an odt to be displayed in LibreOffice, along with highlighting, bolding, etc.

Comment: With regards to my idea about RS, any line without the pattern of >some text< will be regarded only as a record separator and are not to be included in the final result.  I don't know what challenges come up if there are adjacent lines interpreted as a record separator, but seems like that would be no problem as the ‘record’ in between would be nothing.